# Using a control from the main form on subforms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, visual-studio-2013

My main form contains a `TextBox` control that will be used throughout the application as a notepad-like feature.

Some of the subforms that are called from the main form will share the `Text` property of the main form's TextBox, which will not be visible - only the ones in the subforms will.

I'm using an extended `Form` for each subform, and they are being called using `ShowDialog()`.

**What's the best way to "share" this text between all subforms and the main form?**

Please forgive my broken English.

Comment: You could make a global property, that can be accessed from other forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class having a public static property which points to some function, then use this property as method on other forms. You should initialize this property on the initialization of your main form.

E.g.

```
public class Utility
{
    public static Action<string> SetNotePadValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Utility.SetNotePadValue = (s) =>
        {
            // textBox1 is a control on this form
            this.textBox1.AppendText(s + "\r\n");
        };
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this will set value in Form1's textBox1
        Utility.SetNotePadValue("Some text");
    }
}
```

Comment: Static! I'm using a static class for some common functions and never thought of it.... Thanks, that will do.

Comment: Why extract the event to another class?  There's no reason to not have the event in `Form2` itself, and it need not be static.  It can also be an `event`, rather than just a delegate, since that is what it conceptually represents.

Comment: Problems with this solution include 1. The ability for any other class, besides `Form2`, to invoke the event 2. Any code, even code that knows nothing about `Form2`, can subscribe to it 3. If there are no handlers when you invoke it you'll get a NRE 4. It's not clear to a subscriber what the source of the event is 5. If you have multiple popups they don't have separate events.

Comment: @Servy, `Utility.SetNodePadValue` <- this is a pointer to function NOT an `event`, `Form1` is setting the function body in this property, while other `Form`s will be using this method to add the text in `Form1`'s `textBox1` control. `event` approach is also good, but in this way you have to add the event on every `Form`, while this approach is simple for OP's given scenario. The goal is to have a central point which can be used as to create logging, etc. Similar to Tracing, where you add listeners, and you call 1 static method of `Trace` class, which sends the input to all listeners.

Comment: @sallushan Yes, I'm aware that it's a delegate, and not an event.  I said as much in my comment.  My point was that it *should be an `event`*.  That it's not is improper design as it represents an event (not the keyword) from a conceptual standpoint.  Since it is conceptually an event, the code should reflect that.  That there is one central event, despite the fact that there are potentially multiple sources, is *exactly the problem*.  You *don't want to do that*.  It is very hard to work with such an event.  They *should* be tied to each instance of the form.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do here is to create a new event on your form:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public event Action<string> TextChanged; //TODO consider renaming

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = TextChanged;
        if(handler != null)
            handler(textbox.Text);
    }
}
```

The main form can then subscribe to this event when creating the form:

```
Form2 popup = new Form2();
popup.TextChanged += text => DoSomethingWithText(text);
popup.ShowDialog();
```